# Import TAB file into MYSQL: I get null values for my attributes except the first column

Tags: mysql, import, tabs

I have check the forum but haven't found an answer.
I have upload a TAB file to a MySQL database after creating the table "My_Table";
However when I check my data, The first column shows the corresponding data but the other columns are 'NULL', There are no data. 
I have 9 variables, only the first one shows values.

This is the script I used to upload my TAB file: 
**LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Documents/DATA/My_File.tab' INTO TABLE My_Table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';**

Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: You should add the table structure and a sample of your file

Answer (score 0):

I found the error: I was missing a syntaxe below my load code:

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Documents/DATA/My_File.tab' INTO TABLE My_Table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
**(column1, column 2; .... column n);**

Hope it will  help someone!!! :)